# How can I tell a class to use methods of another class?

Tags: java

I'll try to keep this concise. I want to code an ADT called smartADT that chooses a data structure to use based on the number of entries in a list. For example, if I'm given a list of 50,000 employees I will tell smartADT to use a sortedLinkedList, if it's more than that, I'll use a BST and so on, but for this example I am passing the size of 50000. My question is how do I tell my smartADT to use add, delete, find methods from the linkedList class (that is already implemented)?

This is what I have so far:

```
    public class SmartADT{
        int size;
        
        SmartADT(int size){
            this.size = size;
            SetSmartADT(size);
        }

        public void SetSmartADT(int size){
            //size is 50000, tell smartADT to use linked list
        }

        public void add(SmartADT temp, int data){
             //add in linked list
        }

        public void remove(SmartADT temp, int data){
             //delete in linked list
        }

        public static void main(String [] args) {
            SmartADT sadt = new SmartADT(50000); 
    }
}
```

After I run it, how can I pass the linkedList as SmartADT and use linked list methods for the operations I need? Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Find a group of concrete data structure implementations that share the same interface (*e.g.,* the `Set`, `Collection` or `List` interfaces). Afterwards, declare (in your class `SmartADT`) the field (let us named *employees*) that will be holding the collection of *employees*, and make it of the type of the common interface (let us use `List` as an example):

```
private final List <Employees> employees;
```

In the `SmartADT` constructor assign to the field *employees* the concrete implementations of the `List` interface based on your size constraints.

```
SmartADT(int size){
    this.size = size;
    SetSmartADT(size);
    if(size > ....) employees = new ArrayList<>();
    else if(size > ... && ... < size) employees = new LinkedList<>();
    .... 
}
```

Naturally, you need to check the implementation details of each collection (*e.g.,* `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`) that you want to use, and verify that they fit your needs.

Based on your code, the common interface to be chosen, needs (at least) to implement the methods `add` and `remove`, which is the case of all the interfaces that I have mentioned. The last step that you need to do is to forward the calls to the methods `add` and `remove` methods (from the class `SmartADT`) to those from the concrete implementation assigned to the field *employees*:

```
public void add(...){
     .... 
    employees.add(...);
}

public void remove(...){
     ...
     employees.remove(...);
}
```

You can improve upon what I have posted by moving the concern of assigning the collection to the employees to a separate class and apply the [factory pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm).